# Replacing variable in an equation with an Interpolating function polynomial and plotting residual

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I was trying to plot the residual for the solution of my PDE. However, I was unsure about a couple of things.

1. I imported the data and created an Interpolation polynomial with `ListInterpolation`
2. I am trying to replace the dependant variable `h` in my equation with the interpolation polynomial, `solution` using `replace` or `/.`
3. I would need to plot this equation for different/consecutive steps in time to see what the residual looks like. (`residual = equation(t) - equation(t-1)`)

Either all this or is there any way I could just generate the residual from some magic mathematica function?

Should I be defining something as a function of time, which is one of the arguments (? is this the right word) in the interpolating function polynomial?

The notebook and data files are [**attached**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/residuals.zip) for anyone's convenience.

I can't seem to put my finger on the problem but I can't plot the residuals. I apologize if the question is sophomoric but I can't seem to master mathematica at all like other programming environments.

## Minimum working example:

### Equation solver (script file)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

$HistoryLength=0;
$pwf=$InputFileName;
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq0,EvapThickFilm,h,Bo,ϵ,K1,δ,Bi,m,r]
Eq0[h_,{Bo_,ϵ_,K1_,δ_,Bi_,m_,r_}]:=\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t\)]h\)+Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h]+h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]]+(δ h^3)/(Bi h+K1)^3 Grad[h]+m (h/(K1+Bi h))^2 Grad[h]]+ϵ/(Bi h+K1) + (r)D[D[(h^2/(K1+Bi h)),x] h^3,x] ==0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x,y,z]];
EvapThickFilm[Bo_,ϵ_,K1_,δ_,Bi_,m_,r_]:=Eq0[h[x,y,t],{Bo,ϵ,K1,δ,Bi,m,r}];
TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[Bo,ϵ,K1,δ,Bi,m,r]];


L=79.5788; TMax=12500*100;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
Kvar[t_]:=  Piecewise[{{1,t<=1},{2,t>1}}]
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol=h/.NDSolve[{
(*Bo,ϵ,K1,δ,Bi,m,r*)

EvapThickFilm[0,1*10^-6,1,0.001,1,2*0.025,0],
h[0,y,t]==h[L,y,t],
h[x,0,t]==h[x,L,t],
(*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)
h[x,y,0]==1+(-0.05 Cos[2π x/L] -0.05 Sin[2 π x/L])(Cos[2π y/L])
},
h,
{x, 0, L},
{y,0, L},
{t, 0, TMax},
Method->{"LSODA","MaxDifferenceOrder"->12},
MaxStepFraction->1/50,
PrecisionGoal->3
][[1]]




{TMin,TRup}=InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[3]];
hSolGridData=InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[hSol];
hSolCoords=InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol];
finalStep=InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol][[3]];
(*rupture=NumberForm[N[TRup/100],6];*)
rupture=TRup/100;

$parameterfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".dat"];
Export[$parameterfile, {0, 100, 0, 0.0001, 35.1, 7.02, 0, 3, 1, 5, SetPrecision[rupture,5]}];
$matfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".mat"];
Export[$matfile,hSolGridData];
(*Exports time step data*)
$timefile=StringJoin[$pwf,"_time",".mat"];
Export[$timefile,InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol][[3]]];

hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol];
{TMin,TRup}=InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[3]];
Length[hGrid];
{nX,nY,nT}=Drop[Dimensions[hGrid],-1];

fac=0.98;


$epsfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0",".eps"];
$pngfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0",".png"];
$epsfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup",".eps"];
$pngfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup",".png"];
ic=Plot3D[hSol[x,y,0*TRup],{x,0,L},{y, 0, L},

PlotRange->{{0,L},{0,L},{0,3.5}},
BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Plain",FontSize->18},
PlotPoints->65,
ColorFunction->GrayLevel
];
Export[$epsfile0,ic,ImageSize->{350,350}];
Export[$pngfile0,ic,ImageResolution->350];
rupProfile=Plot3D[hSol[x,y,fac*TRup],{x,0,L},{y, 0, L},

PlotRange->{{0,L},{0,L},{0,3.5}},
BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Plain",FontSize->18},
PlotPoints->65,
ColorFunction->GrayLevel
];
Export[$epsfileRup,rupProfile,ImageSize->{350,350}];
Export[$pngfileRup,rupProfile,ImageResolution->350];

dataxy=Import[$matfile];
datat=Import[$timefile];


(*$epsfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0_dft",".eps"];
$pngfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0_dft",".png"];
$epsfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup_dft",".eps"];
$pngfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup_dft",".png"];
FDataFirst=Abs[Fourier[dataxy[[All,All,1]]]];
dftfirst=MatrixPlot[FDataFirst]*)
```

### Data collection where I try to "replace" dependant variable with inter. polynomial

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
L = 79.5788;
dataxy = Import[
   "/home/dnaneet/Desktop/residuals/L_lambda_max_1wl_zg_E_0001_Cos.\
mat"];
datat = Import[
   "/home/dnaneet/Desktop/residuals/L_lambda_max_1wl_zg_E_0001_Cos_\
time.mat"];
solution = ListInterpolation[dataxy, {{0, L}, {0, L}, Flatten[datat]}];
trup = Max[Flatten[datat]]
tsrup = Ceiling[
   0.95 Flatten[Position[Ceiling[Flatten[datat]], Ceiling[trup]]]];
ts = tsrup[[1]];

Clear[Eq0, FilmEqn, h, Bo, ϵ, K1, δ, Bi, m, r]
Eq0[h_, {Bo_, ϵ_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t\)]h\) + 
   Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h] + 
     h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (δ h^3)/(Bi h + K1)^3 Grad[h] + 
     m (h/(K1 + Bi h))^2 Grad[h]] + ϵ/(
   Bi h + K1) + (r) D[D[(h^2/(K1 + Bi h)), x] h^3, x] /. 
  h -> solution[All, All, xtime]
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
FilmEqn[Bo_, ϵ_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_] := 
  Eq0[h[x, y, t], {Bo, ϵ, K1, δ, Bi, m, r}];

TraditionalForm[
 FilmEqn[0, 10^-6, 1, 10^-3, 1, 0.05, 
  0]](*Eqn=Simplify[FilmEqn[0,10^-6,1,10^-3,1,0.05,0]];*)
```

The film plot should look like this:

[image: Plot obtained from Plot3D]

My interpretation of the **residual**
Any thoughts or comments?

> ```
> Plot3D[
>  solution[x, y, 100000] - solution[x, y, 99999],
>  {x, 0, L},
>  {y, 0, L}
>  ]
> ```

[image: Residual - the value is about 10^-6 ..ish]

Comment: The question is good, but you should reduce your problem to a minimal working example. What you have here, namely `ListInterpolation`, sample-data, equation, ... which can all be shown with a small example which can be completely included here. Meaning, I don't have to download a notebook, because you post all code here and create random example data. The dropbox thing will not live forever and later, people cannot not take advantage of your question and the answers because it is incomplete.

Comment: To give you a tip: this `solution[All, All, 1000]` is no list access and if you intended it like this, then you probably express the thing you want in a wrong way.

Comment: @halirutan will do that. I didn't get a no list access however....

Comment: @halirutan the code spans several pages long. I wouldn't want to read a question with code that was over a hundred lines long. And I

Comment: @halirutan min. working ex etc. provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making a silly mistake by considering `solution` as a `List` when you have defined it as a `InterpolatingFunction` object. Here is little modification which may help

```
Clear[Eq0, FilmEqn, h, Bo, ϵ, K1, δ, Bi, m, r]
Eq0[h_, {Bo_, ϵ_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t\)]h\) + 
Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h] + 
 h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (δ h^3)/(Bi h + K1)^3 Grad[h] + 
 m (h/(K1 + Bi h))^2 Grad[h]] + ϵ/(
Bi h + K1) + (r) D[D[(h^2/(K1 + Bi h)), x] h^3, x];
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
FilmEqn[Bo_, ϵ_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_, time_] := 
Eq0[solution[x, y, time], {Bo, ϵ, K1, δ, Bi, m, r}]
expr = FilmEqn[0, 10^-6, 1, 10^-3, 1, 0.05, 0, time];
fun[a_, b_, t_] := Evaluate[expr /. x -> a /. y -> b /. time -> t];
Plot3D[fun[x, y, 100000], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, PlotPoints -> 40,Mesh ->None,
ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[(fun[x, y, #] - fun[x, y, # - 1]), {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
PlotLabel -> "eq(t)-eq(t-1) at t:= " <> ToString[#]] &
```

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that an interpolating function can be manipulated as a list. It responds to `Dimensions`...

Comment: Also, do you have an opinion on my definition of the residual? `residual = equation(t) - equation(t-1)` 

I can't quite see where you calculate the residual although what you have plotted seems to be it! `:-/`

Comment: @drN I am simply plotting `FilmEqn` as a function of `x` and `y` for a given `t=100000`. You so far have not given any definition of `equation(t)`. If `equation(t)=FilmEqn(x,y,t)`?

Comment: Well, the plot that you have is incorrect. The plot should look like my most recent edit. `equation(t)` is ust a generic name I picked to clarify the meaning on residual

Comment: Yes, thats something like what I was trying to do. I'll update/add another answer soon since apparently the CFD community likes it in a certain manner. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer! `:)` thanks for your solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

Faculty members at our math department tell me that this (below) is a more traditional way of plotting the residual.

Apparently I wass a little off with my interpretation of the residual.

> "The residual is how much the solution fails to satisfy the an equation".

As per my question, the first answer by PlatoManiac is correct. However, **my** interpretation of the definition of the residual was flawed.

---

## Minimum working example:

```
Clear[u, L, t, x, y, sol, Eq]
L = 4;
Eq = -D[u[t, x, y], t, t] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + 
   D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + Sin[u[t, x, y]];
uSol = u /. NDSolve[{
     Eq == 0, u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y], 
     u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L], 
     u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0
     }, 
    u,
     {t, 0, L/2}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}
    ][[1]]
```

### Here is a profile plot and a contourplot of the solution:

```
tt = 1.2;
{Plot3D[ uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}], 
 ContourPlot[uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
  ContourLabels -> All]}
```

[image: 3D profile plot] [image: Contour Plot]

### Calculating the residual is as follows:

```
Clear[Res]
Eq
Res[t_, x_, y_] = Abs[Eq /. u -> uSol]

Plot3D[Log[10, Abs[ Res[tt, x, y]]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
 MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image: Plot of the residual]